# Path based on a non-PK unique field in spring-data-rest

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-rest

Given an @Entity declared with the following fields:

```
@Id  
private String idgeo;  
private String isoCtryCd;  
private String randomField;
```

with the default spring configuration I get resource paths ending with .../{idgeo}.
Is there an option in the spring configuration to use other (unique) fields as the resource path ending? In my example it'd be .../{isoCtryCd}

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this feature will be introduced in Spring Data Rest 2.5. Currently there is a 2.5.0.M1 milestone release containing this feature.

This part of the documentation shows how to use a different entity attribute for item resource uris.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.5.0.M1/reference/html/#_customizing_item_resource_uris

Comment: Thank you, Mathias, that'll be a great feature :)